# Folder in GitHub repo automatically load from different repo

Tags: git, github

I have a project that uses different mini projects. Is there a way that I can have a repo of folders that are automatically the "mini" repos?

Comment: `git submodule`?

Comment: git submodules is the answer. - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cricket_007 and Saugat Acharya.

Using `git submodule` you can create a link over.

More info on how:

- Git: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules
- GitHub: https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules